# HashMap not modifiying object contents

Tags: java, pass-by-value

I have a hashmap in which i am putting a reference to an object.

```
     DateTest test100 = new DateTest("ABC",100); 
     dateTestMap.put(96, test100);
```

I am passing this reference variable to a method where i am assigning it a different object and after returning i am pointing the existing reference to the new object as follows:

```
    test100 = datePassingTest(test100);

    private DateTest datePassingTest(DateTest test100)
    {
        DateTest newTest = new DateTest("XYZ", 69);
        test100 = newTest;
        return test100;
    }
```

Well, test100 does get modified to point to the new object but the value stored in map isn't getting updated. Is there something i am missing ?

Thanks,
Adithya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTest test100 = new DateTest("ABC",100); 
dateTestMap.put(96, test100);
```

Here a **copy of reference** (of `test100`) goes and sits into the `dateTestMap` which points to `DateTest("ABC",100)`. Now a **HashMap** `dateTestMap` contains a **new reference** which **points** to the **same object** `DateTest("ABC",100)`

So it can be depicted something like this

[image]

Now when you do

```
test100 = datePassingTest(test100);
```

The **outer** `test100` will point to `new DateTest("XYZ", 69)`, but the **copy reference** present in `dateTestMap` still points to same `DateTest("ABC",100)` object.

[image]

Java is **pass by value** - which essentially means passing the **copy of reference**

Comment: the outer test100 and the test100 reference in the map are same, so if outer test100 is pointing to a new object the map reference should ideally be pointing to the same new bject unless map makes another copy of the reference and stores the reference !

Comment: when i say **reference is copied** , i am very clear that inner and outer `test100` are NOT same.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `test100` is not holding the reference of the object which was created using this `new DateTest("ABC",100);`. It now points to the object created by this `new DateTest("XYZ", 69);`.

If you had done something like `test100.setSomething(150)`, then the change would have been reflected in the map. In this case, it won't as the `test100` now refers a completely different object.

Comment: you mean the test100 reference and the test100 reference inside the map are 2 different copies i.e. i mean are these 2 copies which are pointing to the test100 object ? and after the method returns only the     reference test100 (not the map reference) is pointing to the new object ? Does this mean that java makes a copy of the reference test100 while storing the value in the map ?

Comment: It just stores the reference. Not a copy of the object or something. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/2024761). It clearly explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
test100 = newTest
```

The only thing that is done is that test100 now references the same object as newTest. The object referenced by the original value of test100 is still present but only in the hashmap.

To do what you want, you should try

```
test100.setTime(newTest.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because, you're putting the object inside the map and then modifying the object. Thus, the map would still hold the old object

```
 DateTest test100 = new DateTest("ABC",100); 
 dateTestMap.put(96, test100);           // entry/object added to map

 test100 = datePassingTest(test100);     // object updated

 dateTestMap.put(96, test100);           // map gets new object

// now the map contains the updated object but not the older one.
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are not modifying the `object`. You are just `assigning`.**

Clear explanation in [Language Specification JLS#4.301](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1),

> If two variables contain references to the same object, the state of the object can be modified using one variable's reference to the object, and then the altered state can be observed through the reference in the other variable.